# Double foreign key generation

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity, entity-framework-5

This is a followup-question of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488654/foreign-key-duplicate-in-database), where i had a similar problem. But this is solved now by default foreign key convention.

My problem now is (in short), that my migrations generates

int ReferencedEntityID;
int ReferencedEntity_ReferencedEntityID;

where one is an integer property in my model and the other one is a virtual property.

My migrations generates this:

```
"dbo.Contracts",
            c => new
                {
                    ContractId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    PricePerUnit = c.Double(nullable: false),
                    Unit = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Currency = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    ClientId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    CompanyId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    ArticleId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Client_ClientId = c.Int(),
                    Article_ArticleId = c.Int(),
                })
```

As you can see, Client & Article are referenced twice.

Here are my models

```
public class Client {
    public Client() { }

    [Key]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string Memo { get; set; }
    public bool isMerchant { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
        }
    }

    public int? MerchantReferenceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Client MerchantReference { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Article {

    public Article() { }

    [Key]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool TrackStock { get; set; }
    public int CurrentStock { get; set; }
    public double? Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Contract {

    public Contract() { }

    [Key]
    public int ContractId { get; set; }
    public double PricePerUnit { get; set; }
    public int Unit { get; set; }
    public int Currency { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
  //  [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("CompanyID")]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
   // [ForeignKey("ArticleId")]
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my OnModelCreating()

```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           // modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>().HasRequired(bm => bm.Company).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>().HasRequired(bm => bm.Article).WithMany().HasForeignKey(dl => dl.ArticleId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);//.Map( dl => dl.MapKey("ArticleId"))
            modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>().HasRequired(bm => bm.Client).WithMany().HasForeignKey(dl => dl.ClientId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);//.Map(dl => dl.MapKey("ClientId"))
            modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasRequired(bm => bm.Company).WithMany().HasForeignKey(dl => dl.CompanyId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);//.Map(dl => dl.MapKey("CompanyId"))
            modelBuilder.Entity<Measurement>().HasRequired(bm => bm.Company).WithMany().HasForeignKey(dl => dl.CompanyId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false); //.Map(dl => dl.MapKey("CompanyId"))
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasRequired(bm => bm.Client).WithMany().HasForeignKey(dl => dl.ClientId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false); //.Map(dl => dl.MapKey("ClientId"))
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasRequired(bm => bm.Article).WithMany().HasForeignKey(dl => dl.ArticleId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);//.Map(dl => dl.MapKey("ArticleId"))
            modelBuilder.Entity<IncomingMeasurement>().HasRequired(bm => bm.client).WithMany().HasForeignKey(dl => dl.ClientId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);//.Map(dl => dl.MapKey("ClientId"))
            modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasOptional(c => c.MerchantReference).WithMany().HasForeignKey(dl => dl.MerchantReferenceId); //.Map(dl => dl.MapKey("MerchantReferenceId"))

            //Required fields


            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

What do i have to do, to create them both:

- Required
- Both in one property in my db-schema (as it should)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is OK, even recommended, to have primitive FK properties (like `ArticleId`) accompanying the "real" references. In EF this is called a *foreign key association* as opposed to an *independent association* where there is only a reference (like `Article.Company`).

So you can keep your model the way it is. You just have to specify the foreign keys.

I tried with a few classes in the model *of your previous question* and this produced the desired results:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasMany(a => a.Contracts)
    .WithRequired(c => c.Article)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ArticleID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasMany(c => c.Contracts)
    .WithRequired(c => c.Client)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ClientID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(c => c.Articles)
    .WithRequired(a => a.Company)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Note that I turned around the definitions because when I did it your way, but with `HasForeignKey` it still duplicated the FK fields. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Great, fixed my problem! I didn't reference the entities in my modelbuilder.

Eg. I used .WithMany() instead of .WithMany(dl => dl.Clients) and that generated a duplicate FK. Thanks a lot!